# manipulate the object value without knowing its key

Tags: javascript

I have an object obj and I want to manipulate it's value, but I don't want to write the value hard-coded something like below, is there any better alternative to this below approach

```js
let obj = {a:{x:0}, b:{y:0}};

obj.a[Object.keys(obj.a)[0]] = 1;

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: What do you mean by edit without writing hard coded value ? You need to specify the  property you want to change.

Comment: There's no guarantee object keys will appear in the same order every time, so, your approach is error prone.

Comment: If you would share broader explanation of your use case, you may probably get relevant answers.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a generic function where you can set the value of key without knowing the property names of inside object.

You can call the function with required key and value and get the desired result.

```js
let obj = {a:{x:0}, b:{y:0}};

function assignValue(key, value) {
 obj[key][Object.keys(obj[key])] = value;
}

assignValue('a', 1)

console.log(obj)

let objMultipleInnerKeys = {a:{x:0, z:2}, b:{y:0}};

function assignValueMultipleInnerKeys(key, innerKey, value) {
 objMultipleInnerKeys[key][innerKey] = value;
}

assignValueMultipleInnerKeys('a', 'x', 1)

console.log(objMultipleInnerKeys)
```

Comment: imagine you don't know the key in the inner object is `x`, it could be something random. In this case, using `x` directly on the object won't work (hence you are hardcoding the property)

Comment: @NickParsons Got it. Thanks!

Comment: looks better now, but if the inner object has two keys such as `{x:0, z: 0}` your method will add a third key to the result `"x,z": 1`

Comment: if the inner objects can have multiple keys,then user need to specify in some way that they want to manipulate that particular key. Right ? Like an extra parameter for assignValue function ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. It seems however that the OP wants to change the first occurring key in the object (so they've hardcoded it to get that first key by using `[0]`). Your solution might be fine if OPs nested objects only have one key in them - its hard to tell exactly what the OP is after though

Comment: Agree with you. Thanks for explanation!!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want to loop through them and have different values for x, y or whatever the key is

```js
let obj = {
  a: {
    x: 0
  },
  b: {
    y: 0
  }
};



keys = Object.keys(obj)
for (let i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  key2 = Object.keys(obj[keys[i]])[0];
  // instead of some_value inject an array of values 
  obj[keys[i]][key2] = 'some_value';
}

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: I won't downvote, but for your consideration, your code relies on object keys order ***which is not guaranteed***, so it may give unexpected output.